# Notepad++: Find specified characters, with the excusion

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am not too familiar with regex; similar links in this forum didn't help me to completely understand it.

I'm trying to find the asterisk ("`*`") value within my texts, but only if there is no dot (`.`) immediately preceding of it. Ideally, the results should return all instances of the "`*`" character, except "`.*`".

Is it possible, and if yes, how can it be accomplished?

Comment: `[^\.]\*`, perhaps?

Comment: @esqew: This will not match an asterisk if there is nothing before it.

Answer (score 1):

First, to find asterisk, you need to escape it with backslash.

```
\*
```

Then to find asterisk without preceding dot. You need Negative Look Behind, and don't forget to escape the dot with backslash dot.

```
(?<!\.)\*
```

[See demo here](https://regex101.com/r/j9gjxw/1)

For some info on negative look behind:
https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html